# IOError when trying to convert CSV into dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to try and understand why I get an Error in the following code. The Error is `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f17-yields.csv'`

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import os

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()

dataframeofxls_file = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.basename(url))
print dataframeofxls_file
```

Cheers

Comment: @bernie If I carry out that change I still obtain an error `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. First you are downloading the csv file, not saving it locally, and then trying to open this non-existent local file.

Second, a CSV file is not an Excel file, and so you don't need `pd.ExcelFile` to open it. Try a CSV reader instead. So for example:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'
pd.read_csv(url)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I want the data to be in the form of a Dataframe. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. However, the Output comes out in a very strange form. `     F17 ZERO-COUPON INTEREST RATES ? ANALYTICAL SERIES ? 2009 TO CURRENT  \
0                                                 Title                     
1                                           Description                     
2                                             Frequency`  I was hoping it would be such that the headers would be the same as those in the CSV File and the rows would follow correspondingly.

Comment: That's what the CSV file looks like. Download it and open with a plain editor.

Comment: Thank You. Is there a way to make the data more organized within this Dataframe?

Comment: Not really. That CSV file looks messy but that how it is formatted. If you open it with excel (which supports CSV files) you will have a good overview of how it is organized.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reader function in csv

```
import csv
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.rba.gov.au/statistics/tables/csv/f17-yields.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    print row
```